# Can I install an electrical outlet on furnace closet wall?

Tags: electrical, hvac

I'm remodeling my unfinished basement.  I'm building  a closet to enclose the gas furnace and water heater.  Can I install an electrical outlet on one of the walls?  This would be facing outward toward the living space?  I've tried to find this in the codes and came up empty.  There's plenty of information about the outlets required for services to the furnace.  As well as, wiring distances from the exhausts.  The wall clearances to the furnace are good.  But nothing about a separate electrical branch and outlet in the same space as the gas appliance.

Comment: Remember those appliances have *considerable* air draw if they run on fuel (and are not direct-vent).

Comment: Yes you can have an outlet inside the enclosed area for a gas furnace. Some jurisdictions require both a light and a receptacle. A separate circuit is only required for the furnace itself.

Comment: What's making you think you *can't* do what you describe?